# What's the replacement for lightdm service in Lubuntu 20.04

Tags: lubuntu, services, display-manager

I used to do

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

under Lubuntu 18.04 LTS to solve blackscreen problems sometimes. Now that lightdm is gone in Lubuntu 20.04 LTS,

what is the service equivalent to `lightdm` above that I can use in 20.04?

Comment: I'm certain you could just use `display-manager` (e.g., `systemctl restart display-manager`, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is `sddm`

> sddm is the default display manager that shows up when you first log
>   in to Lubuntu or logout or choose to another session. There is no
>   graphical application to do this currently.

[Lubuntu Manual](https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.1/3.1.9/sddm_configuration.html)